# How to substitute substring in column A with matching string in map table

Tags: postgresql

I want to process `foo`'s Column **A** to become **B**, using the replacement patterns found on a separate table `bar`.

```
CREATE TABLE foo
AS
  SELECT *
  FROM ( VALUES
    ( 'one, 1, two, 2, three, 3' , 'one apple, two bananas, three strawberries' ),
    ( 'one, 1, four, 4, three, 3', 'one apple, four oranges, three strawberries' ),
    ( 'two, 2, four, 4, three, 3', 'two bananas, four oranges, three strawberries' )
  ) AS t(a,b);

CREATE TABLE bar
AS
  SELECT *
  FROM ( VALUES
    ( 'one, 1'    , 'one apple' ),
    ( 'two, 2'    , 'two bananas' ),
    ( 'three, 3'  , 'three strawberries' ),
    ( 'four, 4'   , 'four oranges' )
  ) AS t(pattern,repl);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I wouldn't do this. This is called *"lexicon replacement"*. It's done using [FTS's Thesaurus Dictionary](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html). You can ask another question if you have a problem getting that working and you decide to go down that route.**

That said, if you want to do this recursively, you can. It's certainly doable.

```
WITH RECURSIVE f AS (
  SELECT row_number() OVER (), *
  FROM bar
),
t(orig,working,row) AS (
  SELECT a , a , 0
  FROM foo
  UNION ALL
    SELECT orig, regexp_replace(working,pattern,repl), row+1
    FROM t
    INNER JOIN f
      ON row_number = row+1
)
SELECT orig, working
FROM t
WHERE row = (SELECT count(*) FROM f)
ORDER BY orig;
```

Output

```
           orig            |                    working                    
---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------
 one, 1, four, 4, three, 3 | one apple, four oranges, three strawberries
 one, 1, two, 2, three, 3  | one apple, two bananas, three strawberries
 two, 2, four, 4, three, 3 | two bananas, four oranges, three strawberries
(3 rows)
```

Note if you have a `serial` on `bar` then remove CTE `f`.